# Dojo subscribe treenode select

Tags: dojo

I am using Struts 2 dojo plugin to make html tree. It generate some dojo-html code for tree node

```
<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode"     id="2"    title="car">
```

I want to process tree node click by this

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
dojo.event.topic.subscribe("treeSelected", function treeNodeSelected(message) {

    dojo.io.bind({
        url: "<s:url value='../roseindia/objectsList2.action'/>?categoryId="+message.node.title,
        load: function(type, data, evt) {
            var divDisplay = dojo.byId("displayIt");
            divDisplay.innerHTML=data;
        },
        mimeType: "text/html"
    });

});
```

I can pass title(car)  as message.node.title . I need to pass id not title, but where is not propertie  message.node.id.

How can I get access to id(of treenode) in JavaScript function?

Answer (score 0):

oohhkay, so youre in a 0.4.3 dojo.version!? im not sure how API works in that old a version, however the simplest current api hook is the onClick.

As i recall, with tree.onClick override you will get the `item` and the `TreeNode`, both being objects where the item is reference to your store json data and the treenode is the currently clicked row (dijit Widget, meaning you should have .getChildren, .domNode etc).

So in terms of code, try

```
<div dojoType="struts:StrutsTreeNode"     id="2"    title="car">
  <script type="dojo/method" event="onClick" args="item, treeNode">
     alert(treeNode.id);
     alert(treeNode.domNode.tagName);
     alert(treeNode.domNode.innerHTML.substr(0,30);
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: see http://grokbase.com/t/dojo/dojo-interest/101adyfyan/adding-onclick-event-for-folder-nodes-in-a-dijit-tree

Comment: Thanks for you answer.Yes it is 0.4.3 old version.I have decided don't use this plugin with old dojo version. Now  I am trying to use jquery-treeview.

Comment: yuk! :) you should instead, download the dojo toolkit (or use google cdn) in its new version. Once you understand dojo and start using its AMD / build features, it outperforms jquery. It grants you more or less the same kernel but has a cleaner access to modules (its basically in-a-box, dont have to download, install and setup every class you need)

Comment: Finally I decided to use jquery-treeview plugin instead of dojo based strust-tree.